# Bounded linear functional in Hilbert space is actually inner product with a fixed element

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to do a bit of reading on functional analysis and I've come up with a proof that's different than the one in the book I'm reading. Would greatly appreciate it if someone could check whether this works.

Theorem: In a Hilbert space H, any bounded linear operator f is of the form $f(x)=<x,y>$ for some fixed $y$ (I believe that's to say H=H*?)

My way to go about it: Using some of the previous exercises from the book,
a linear functional $f$ on a Hilbert space is bounded iff the kernel is closed. Let then $K$ be the kernel of $f$ and consider the quotient $H/K$ -though we can also make this into a normed vector space, I think even looking at just the vector space structure will do. First isomorphism theorem says $H/K \equiv Im(f) = \mathbb{R} $ assuming f is non-zero.

Now $K$ is closed, so it is itself a Hilbert space so consider a complete orthonormal system of it, and extend it to a complete orthonormal system of $H$. Since $H/K$ has dim $1$ as a vector space, there must be precisely one element in the othonormal system of $H$ that was not in the orthonormal system of $K$

Thus, any $x \in H$ can be written as $x=ty+n$ for some real $t, n \in ker(f)$ and $y$ that has norm 1 and $<y,n>=0$ for all $n \in ker(f)$.

Thus we see $f(x)=tf(y)$ and $<x,y>=t$ so replacing $y$ by $yf(y)$ should do the trick.

I fell like this works, but the book provides a different approach, so being new to the subject I thought it's worth making sure. Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: These are called bounded (or continuous) linear *functional*s, not operators! And It is the Reisz-Frechet representation theorem that $\mathcal H \cong \mathcal H^*$, (antilinear isomorphism.)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. It's edited now

Comment: Why is $<x,y>=t$ ?